# Enter to or exit from any state other than the one that issued the visa

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I know this question has been asked and answered many times and the answer is that "Yes you can enter or exit from any Schengen state".

I am still unclear about my situation.

My work has issued me multiple entry Schengen visa type C,valid for 90 days stay and with Sweden as main entry.

I am traveling to Sweden for business purpose but before going there I need to attend a workshop in Czech Republic. I am taking a return ticket from Rome , from Rome I will take a domestic flight to Czech Republic , attend workshop there and from there take a domestic flight to Sweden to attend business and return to Rome after my trip and Exit from Rome.

The purpose of returning back to Rome is that I want to visit and travel the city for 2 or 3 days and then take an exit from there.

Now back to my question,I have followed several posts saying that "You should at least once use the VISA for the purpose it was intended for". Passport is stamped once on entering to Schengen area and later on exiting from it. 
How would my passport indicate that I have visited Sweden when my entry and exit is not from there?
I will use my visa for the intended purpose but border guards in Rome, could ask me about the purpose of my entering and existing from Rome as they will not know if I have fulfilled the purpose of my VISA.

How should I be prepared to deal all these situations ?

Comment: What do you mean by "with Sweden as main entry"? There is no such concept in the Schengen visa code. Do you mean that Sweden issued the visa?

Comment: Yes Swedish embassy issued the visa.

Comment: From my multiple past experiences when I still had to use visa, nobody in Rome FCO took any care even to find the visa in the passport. Just looked for the empty space to put a stamp in. The paperwork described in the answer, however, may be useful when you apply for your visa the next time, so make sure you keep it.

Answer (score 6):

Your passport will not indicate that you have traveled to Sweden. You should therefore be prepared to show by other means that your trip reflected the travel proposed in your visa application. For example, you can carry the boarding passes from your internal flights to and from Sweden, as well as receipts for meals and accommodation.  You could also show evidence of your business meetings or other business activities in Sweden.

Comment: Right!. Also about the entry to Rome, I could be asked the purpose of my entry from Rome and not from Sweden ? if yes then what could be the suitable reason keeping in mind that I am going to workshop in some other Schengen state?

Comment: @Sajjad just tell the truth. Tell them why you booked your flights to Rome, and tell them that you plan to spend 2 or 3 days there as a tourist. They might ask why you've flown to Rome instead of Sweden, but there's nothing wrong with doing so. It's completely within the rules.

Comment: It would justify my purpose for the time but what about applying for VISA again in future? As I've also read that , in future visa can be rejected because its purpose wasn't fulfilled in past.

Comment: @Sajjad but you are saying that you will fulfill the purpose for which you applied for the visa. So you will not be subject to future refusals for failing to fulfill the purpose.

Comment: Yes, but my passport will show otherwise(no entry or exit stamp), so should I keep my hotel bookings and other relevant documents that show my stay at Sweden safe and present them at the time of applying again for visa?

Comment: @Sajjad I would present them only if asked, but it probably wouldn't hurt to present them up front. If you are so worried about it, hire a lawyer.